# Retain format jquery paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having trouble retain the format of the text when pasting into a text area housed by TinyMCE. I have seen that a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021047/retain-ms-word-formatting-when-pasting-into-tinymce-3) has been asked, but has not been answered so thought I'd try my luck.

I have tried various variations of the [TMCE configuration](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration), but no dice and I'm not sure if I've missed something.

TinyMCE is working, all but when I use my drop downs to paste content into the text area. The paste into the text area is done through code behind VB.NET and the files being accessed are txt files which have spaces and line breaks; this format is kept correct without TinyMCE's presence, so I am not sure what to do regarding TMCE, and whether anyone has any solutions for this.

If any more code is required please say and I'll amend but this issue appears to be with TMCE only.

Thank you.

```
    <script src="../Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            menubar: false,
            paste_retain_style_properties: true,
            paste_merge_formats: true,
            selector: "textarea"
```

**Update**

I am getting a .txt file via a drop down box that pastes into a text file using code behind, see below example, ideally I want to achieve this programmatically without having to edit the source files as that'll be a real pain.

VB.NET

```
    Dim ddl2 As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim ctl2 As TextBox = DirectCast(ddl2.NamingContainer.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)

        If ddl2.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        ctl2.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Templates\message.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are doing but if you take txt files and want to keep their formatting in an HTML editor, you will, most likely, need to replace the new lines (\n and/or \r) with the HTML `<br />` tag.

Comment: That'll do, thanks - do you know a way to get this to work without having to edit the files? At present they won't have to edited often, but it'll be a pain to do it if they become more prevalent.

Comment: string.Replace or some regex? When you load the file on the server you can get its contents as a string and manipulate it. In this way you will not need to change your files at all. If you are using them as HTML template you may want to move them to real HTML files, though. If you are open to commercial options, Telerik's editor has built-in templates support - see the Template Manager dialog: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/filemanagers/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately not, AJAX is out of the window due to post back issues with the pages other controls that causes conflict.